# Oracle APEX 18.2, column filter for Popup LOV columns in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm on Oracle APEX18.2

I have an Interactive Grid where two columns are Popup LOV based. The return value of these is text.
However I'm not able to have the column filtering feature work for these columns in the interactive grid.
When I click on the column header of these columns the filter drop down comes up empty. Even the Inetractive grid search-box doesn't search these columns. I cannot see the filter options in the attributes of these columns in the developer. I can see it for the other columns in the grid.
Is this a bug? Is there a way to have the search work for these columns?

Answer (score 0):

As not much details listed here, I can see below possibilities :

1. return_value and display_value are not marked correctly in your LOVs causing empty list
2. You will also need to have default value in case you want preloaded data
3. Ensure you have cascading LOV parent item for 2nd LOV popup to populate data dynamically. -> [image: see this image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps in your Apex Page Designer

1. Click on the Modal LOV column in the IG.
2. In the Attributes of the column search for Column Filter
3. Column Filter -> LOV Type => Use List of Values.

[Image showing where to enable column filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLmL.png)

**Note: If you have filled the Cascading LOV Parent Column(s) property in List of Values Section then the Column filter will be hidden because the LOV has a parent column and so apex will not be able to filter the column** ([Oracle Support Ticket Link](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2289512_1.html))

Comment: Thank you for your response.
"Note: If you have filled the Cascading LOV Parent Column(s) property in List of Values Section then the Column filter will be hidden because the LOV has a parent column and so apex will not be able to filter the column"
Can you explain why?

Comment: The column value is already dependent on the cascading lov parent column (ie).. the column value is populated based on the value from the parent columns, so it's not static, it may vary based on the change of the parent column.. so apex internally won't be able to set a filter for such dynamic columns. So if the filter is mandatory, you will have to choose other methods ,eg: using JS or jquery to populate the lov values instead of using cascading lov parent.